# JavaScript for InDesign to extract the text of a paragraph with a specified and known paragraphstyle

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign

I am new to JavaScript and even newer to InDesign. Could you please help me on this problem ?

I need to extract the text of 3 cells of a tab. Those 3 cells each have a dedicated paragraphstyle : print.rv, print.qty, print.ref.
The tab is of that form on my page (in a textframe):

| Ref | ref_number (paragraphstyle: print.ref) |
| --- | --- |
| Quantity | qty_number (paragraphstyle : print.qty) |
| Recto/Verso | recto_verso or not (paragraphstyle : print.rv) |

So i need to extract separately each string of the 2nd column. (The final objective is to write those string in the name of the exported pdf version of the project).

Thanks for your help :-) !

Answer (score 1):

**Input:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
var doc = app.activeDocument

// convert all tables into the text
doc.stories.everyItem().tables.everyItem().convertToText("\t", "\r");

// for every line in the text: remove all characters from the start up to the tab symbol
app.findGrepPreferences.findWhat = "^.+\t";
app.changeGrepPreferences.changeTo = "";
doc.changeGrep();

// get all paragraphs from first text frame
var pgfs = doc.textFrames[0].paragraphs.everyItem().getElements();

// your styles (they can be obtained automatically)
var styles = ["rv", "qty", "ref"];

// 2D-array with paragraphs grouped by style
var pgf_groups = [];

// fill the array with paragraphs
for (var s=0; s<styles.length; s++) {
    var style_group = [] // array for every style
    for (var i=0; i<pgfs.length; i++) {
        if (pgfs[i].appliedParagraphStyle.name == styles[s])
            style_group.push(pgfs[i]);
    }
    pgf_groups.push(style_group); // push the array into 2D-array
}

// output (get contents from the 2D-array and join it in a readable string)

function get_text(pgfs) {
    var txt = "";
    for (var i=0; i<pgfs.length; i++) txt = txt + pgfs[i].contents + "\n";
    return txt;
}

msg = ""
+ styles[0] + ":\n" + get_text(pgf_groups[0]) + "\n\n"
+ styles[1] + ":\n" + get_text(pgf_groups[1]) + "\n\n"
+ styles[2] + ":\n" + get_text(pgf_groups[2]);

alert(msg);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Sorry, I don't get what do you mean 'to write those string in the name of the exported pdf version of the project'.

Actually the implementation heavily depends on many details. Does your document contain another text beside the table? (I supposed your document contain just the table and nothing else). In case if there is another text, will you select the table manually? Does the table always have 3 row? (I supposed there can be many rows) How exactly you will open the document? How you will run the script? Etc...

Probably for simplest case it would be enough the first five lines of the script: convert the table into text and get rid of characters before tab symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yuri for your answer ! First your code is running but it doesn't return any value. I don't understand why haha. I think the issue is line 12 as I don't have an only text box I don't select the good paragraph styles but I don't know how to get every paragraphs styles of the page :/.

Moreover as you said, I should have been more precise on my post.
I work on files which are composed of multiple pages, those pages all have multiple text boxes but they all have one in common attached to the template. It is from this text box that I want to extract the data, it contains the table I presented in the original post. The script will be executed directly from InDesign.

Then I must export individually each page in a PDF and write the informations I got from the table in the title of each file.

For example if my file is called test.indd and my first page has ref_number: 05, qty_number: 3 and is a recto i should export the first page as a pdf called test_05_3_recto.pdf.

Thanks for your help and thanks for your time !

Comment: _i should export the first page as a pdf called test_05_3_recto.pdf._ what would be a name for second and other pages? Can you share an example of your indd document (IDML would be even better format). You can upload files here: https://transferxl.com/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I didn't see your answer until today :/. I will upload an example file, the 2nd, 3rd, etc... pages would be named the same way the first one is named. Each page has a table attached with the informations written inside it.
Here is the link: https://www.transferxl.com/08VGqQ4DkjtCm